# Cleaner solution to parse message and return json

Tags: javascript, json

I'm writing a function to subscribe data transmitting through bluetooth and parse it, finally return specific info into output json.

My message format will be 'Header','Id','Ggid','Ppayload','Ttimestamp','AsigA','BsigB'. In this format, there's no space between each segment but one comma. Only Id and Header are necessary in this format. Header is static, and will always start with an 'H'. Other info will start with a capital letter except 'Id'. For example, Id segment can be 12345678, but payload segment will be P12345678. Currently, I'm having a really complicated code to parse this info.

Example Message is a string: H,00198601,GLOCATE,P762,T1.50,A64,B67

```
var len = Message.length;
app.outputTagJson.Tag = {};
if (len >= 2)
{
    app.outputTagJson.Tag.tagID = Message[1];
    app.outputTagJson.Tag.isLost = "False";
    if (len >= 3)
    {
        app.outputTagJson.Tag.groupID = Message[2].slice(1,Message[2].length);
        if (len >= 4)
        {
            app.outputTagJson.Tag.payload = Message[3].slice(1,Message[3].length);
            if (len >= 5)
            {
                app.outputTagJson.Tag.timeStamp = Message[4].slice(1,Message[4].length);
                if (len >= 6)
                {
                    app.outputTagJson.Tag.sigStrenthA = Message[5].slice(1,Message[5].length);
                    if (len >= 7)
                    {
                        app.outputTagJson.Tag.sigStrenthB = Message[6].slice(1,Message[6].length);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm thinking a generic regular expression to cut this format in javascript, but I'm not farmiliar with it. So is there any cleaner solution without using regular expression or if I have to use regular expression, how can I approach that?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the message you get?

Comment: Can you share actual examples of your input and your expected output? The code you shared seems to start somewhere in the middle... like you've already split the string on commas and removed the single quotes perhaps? It also seems from your code like you want to strip the first character off of every value except ID?

Comment: @smarx, yes, I've already split the original string by a comma, I will add the sample message right away.

Comment: It's also unclear what to do in the case where there are missing fields. I guess you need to look at the first letter to disambiguate? E.g. if the data is `'Head1','12345','A54'`, you need to look at the `A` to determine that the third field is `sigStrengthA`, right? Your existing code seems to assume that no fields can be skipped... if there's a `sigStrengthA`, then all the fields before it must also exist. Is that a valid assumption?

Comment: Yes it is. Those fields must exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try?

```js
var input = 'H,00198601,GLOCATE,P762,T1.50,A64,B67';

var fieldMap = {
    G: 'groupID',
    P: 'payload',
    T: 'timeStamp',
    A: 'sigStrengthA', // NOTE: you misspelled "strength"
    B: 'sigStrengthB',
};

var fields = input.split(',');
var tag = {};

tag.tagID = fields[1];

fields.slice(2).forEach(function (field) {
    tag[fieldMap[field[0]]] = field.substring(1);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(tag, null, 4));

// Output:
// {
//     "tagID": "00198601",
//     "groupID": "LOCATE",
//     "payload": "762",
//     "timeStamp": "1.50",
//     "sigStrengthA": "64",
//     "sigStrengthB": "67"
// }
```

**EDIT**

Another solution that relies purely on field order (now that I see the fields are always in the same order):

```js
var input = 'H,00198601,GLOCATE,P762,T1.50,A64,B67';

var fieldNames = [
    'tagID',
    'groupID',
    'payload',
    'timeStamp',
    'sigStrengthA',
    'sigStrengthB',
];

var tag = {};
var fields = input.split(',');
for (var i = 1; i < fields.length; i++) {
    tag[fieldNames[i-1]] = fields[i].substring(i === 1 ? 0 : 1);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(tag, null, 4));

// Output:
// {
//     "tagID": "00198601",
//     "groupID": "LOCATE",
//     "payload": "762",
//     "timeStamp": "1.50",
//     "sigStrengthA": "64",
//     "sigStrengthB": "67"
// }
```

Comment: Yep, I just forgot to map the field. And substring is probably the best solution I think.

Comment: @LingboTang `substring` and `slice` do the same thing, `substring` just has some differences in how it handles some parameters.

Comment: One problem is that you didn't handle the case of isLost, but I added the block now.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a good opportunity to use the fact that in a `switch` statement, it keeps executing statements below until it reaches a `break`. Also, `slice` goes to the end when you don't specify a second parameter.

```js
var input = "H,00198601,GLOCATE,P762,T1.50,A64,B67",
    message = input.split(","),
    tag = {};
switch (message.length) {
  default:
  case 7: tag.sigStrengthB = message[6].slice(1);
  case 6: tag.sigStrengthA = message[5].slice(1);
  case 5: tag.timeStamp = message[4].slice(1);
  case 4: tag.payload = message[3].slice(1);
  case 3: tag.groupID = message[2].slice(1);
  case 2: tag.tagID = message[1];
          tag.isLost = "False";
  case 1:
  case 0: break;
}
console.log(tag);
```

Comment: Yep, it is good to have the slice function to cut the first one off.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code (I don't know exactly what it is), it can rewritten like this:

```
var len = Message.length;
var props = ['tagID','groupID','payload','timeStamp','sigStrenthA','sigStrenthB'];
app.outputTagJson.Tag = {};
if (len >= 2)
{
    app.outputTagJson.Tag[props[0]] = Message[1];
    app.outputTagJson.Tag.isLost = "False";
    for(var i=3;i<=len;i++)
        app.outputTagJson.Tag[props[i-2]] = Message[i-1].slice(1,Message[i-1].length);
}
```

Comment: almost did that too but notice different properties in various `if`

Comment: For len>=4, I have more info to add in json than just groupID

Comment: how is it now? it should be ok now.

Comment: Yes, it's cleaner, I'm giving you an upvote to save your answer.